# extract specific key value from json in bash if key matches

Tags: json, regex, linux, bash, shell

I have a json content (output.json)

```
{"project": {"id": "A", "content": [{"name": "XYZ", "location": "Berlin", "comments":""}, {"name": "ABC", "location": "NewYork", "comments": "Hwllo"}, {"name": "DEF", "location": "Paris", "comments": "Success"}]}}
```

I would like to extract `location` key with value when `name` matches say `ABC` from the above json using bash or shell commands

I tried something like below which gives be content within curly braces. but not sure on searching specific key.

```
cat output.json | grep -o -e "{.*}"
```

Output expectations:
   if `name` matches `ABC`, get output as `"location":"NewYork"`

Any suggestions on processing further?

Comment: For extracting from json you should use jq if you can. According to authors "jq is like sed for JSON data".

Answer (score 3):

For extracting from json you should use jq if you can. According to authors "jq is like sed for JSON data" [(source)](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

In your case it should be:

```
$ jq -r '.project' output.json | jq -r '.content' | jq '.[] | select(.name=="ABC")' | jq -r '.location'
```

Output will be:

```
NewYork
```

To get output which you required so:

```
"location":"NewYork"
```

You can use:

```
echo "\"location\":$(jq -r '.project' output.json | jq -r '.content' | jq '.[] | select(.name=="ABC")' | jq '.location')"
```

Before you use jq you should install it on Debian and Ubuntu it will be:

```
$ sudo apt install jq
```

for other OS you should check [this site](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/).

Comment: Thank you. Looks interesting, gonna try now :)

Answer (score 1):

There may be better ways to do it, in a quick twisted way is here.

```
cat output.json | sed 's/"name"/\n"name"/g' | grep '"name"' | awk -F',' '{print $2}'
```

Add `| grep <preferred name>` also if need to filter based on name.

Comment: Thank you. This is good. but unfortunately, key location is not always in second place. `awk` with `$2` is like hardcoded.

Comment: ohh .. ok then we can add one more sed before that, like `cat output.json | sed 's/"name"/\n"name"/g' | grep '"name"' | sed 's/"location"/\n"location"/g' | awk -F',' '{print $1}'` ... ;)

Comment: When I do this... I get both name and location key value pair. I still need to use `tail -1` at the end which doesnt look good when the order is different

Comment: Yea its true ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use Perl

```
$ perl -0777 -lne ' while(/"name":\s+"ABC",\s+"location":\s+(\S+)/msg) { print "$1\n" } ' output.json
"NewYork",
$ cat output.json
{"project": {"id": "A", "content": [{"name": "XYZ", "location": "Berlin", "comments":""}, {"name": "ABC", "location": "NewYork", "comments": "Hwllo"}, {"name": "DEF", "location": "Paris", "comments": "Success"}]}}
$
```

Comment: glad to hear that!.. please consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

Please use a JSON parser for processing JSON.
With [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) it's as simple as:

```
xidel -s output.json -e '($json//content)()[name="ABC"]/location'
```

Alternatively:

```
xidel -s output.json -e '$json/(.//content)()[name="ABC"]/location'

or in full:

xidel -s output.json -e '$json/project/(content)()[name="ABC"]/location'
```

The above is XPath notation ([example #11, Reading JSON](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html#examples)). Dot notation (like `jq`) is also possible:

```
xidel -s output.json -e '($json).project.content()[name="ABC"].location'
```

**[edit]**
Commands above put out `NewYork` and I just realized you require the output to be `"location":"NewYork"`. Xidel can do that too:

```
xidel -s output.json -e '($json//content)()[name="ABC"]/concat("""location"":""",location,"""")'
```

**[/edit]**